# Show that $ \ B \subset A \iff (A-B) \cup B = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Question:

Show that $ \ B \subset A \iff (A-B) \cup B = A$

My attempt:

**First we prove $ \ B \subset A  \implies (A-B) \cup B = A$**

Assume $ \ B \subset A$

WTS $ \ (A-B) \cup B = A$

First show $ \ (A-B) \cup B \subseteq A$

$ x \in (A-B) \cup B \implies x\in A-B$ or $ \ x \in B$

If $ \ x \in A -B \implies x \in A$. Otherwise $ \ x\in B \implies x\in A$, since $ \ B \subset A$.

Now we show $  A \subseteq \ (A-B) \cup B$

$ x \in A \implies x\in A-B \implies x \in (A-B) \cup B$

**Now we prove** $ (A-B) \cup B = A  \implies B \subset A $

Assume $ (A-B) \cup B = A $

WTS $ \ B \subset A$

$ x \in B \implies x\in (A-B) \cup B \implies x\in A$, since  $ (A-B) \cup B = A $

I am not quite sure if this approach is correct. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Why $x \in A \implies x\in A-B \implies x \in (A-B) \cup B$.? (line 11)

Comment: How would I show that $ \ x\in A \implies x \in (A-B) \cup B$ ?

Comment: I think $x\in A \implies x\in B or x\notin B \implies x\in B or x\in A-B \implies x \in (A-B) \cup B$.

Comment: If $x\in A$ then either $x\in A - B$ or $x\in A\cap B$. Notice how if $x\in A\cap B$, then $x\notin A - B$, that is a small flaw in your reasoning. Besides that, it looks correct.

Comment: Is the rest of my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\color {blue}{B \subset A  \implies (A-B) \cup B = A}$

$\boxed{(A-B) \cup B\subset A}$

$x\in (A-B) \cup B \implies \left\lbrace \begin{array}l x\in A- B\subset A\\ \text{or}\\x\in B\subset A\end{array}\right.\implies(A-B) \cup B\subset A$

$\boxed{A \subset(A-B) \cup B}$

$x\in A \implies\left \lbrace \begin{array}lx\in A-B\\\text{or}\\x\in A\cap B\implies x\in B\end{array}\right.\implies x\in (A- B)\cup B\implies A \subset(A-B) \cup B$

---

$\color{blue}{(A-B) \cup B = A  \implies B \subset A}$

$x\in B\implies x\in (A-B) \cup B \implies x\in A\implies B \subset A$

Answer (score 1):

**Some hints:**

Preferably, do things globally, I mean not considering elements, but using already proved or obvious inclusions

E.g. for $\Longrightarrow $, you know that $A-B\subset A$, and $B\subset A$ by hypothesis. It is well known that $\;[X\subset Y$ **and** $X'\subset Y]\;$ imply $X\cup X'\subset Y$.

Conversely , you only have to prove that, if an element $x\in A$ is not in $B$, it is in ...

For $\Longleftarrow$,  i.e. $(A-B)\cup B=A$ is the hypothesis, just note that we know
for any $X,X'$, we have $X,X'\subset X\cup X'$ by definition.

Answer (score 1):

There is one point that is untrue. You mentioned $x \in A \implies x \in A-B$. That is incorrect.

You may use $A-B = A \cap B^c$ to show that $(A-B)\cup B=A \cup B$. Obviously, $x \in A \implies x \in A \cup B$.

An alternative approach to proving your claim is to prove $B \subseteq A \Leftrightarrow A \cup B =A$. I believe this can easily be proved.

Answer (score 1):

A correct way to prove  that $A \subseteq (A$ \ $B ) \cup B$ is this:

Note that $A$ \ $B$  $=A \cap B^c$.

We will use the De Morgan laws and will prove it with contraposition.

Let $x \notin  (A$ \ $B ) \cup B$ then $$x \in (A \cap B^c)^c \cup B^c \Rightarrow x \in (A^c \cup B) \cap B^c \Rightarrow x \in (A^c \cap B^c) \cup (B^c \cap B)=A^c \cap B^c$$

Thus $x \notin A \Rightarrow    A \subseteq (A$ \ $B ) \cup B$